# Dell Inspiron 600M

Tags: dell, inspiron

Just wondering I want to install ubuntu on my ancient Dell Inspiron 600M is there any drivers I need to download and where can I download it? Thank you in advanced for all who help me on this. -Cheers-

Answer (score 1):

The wonderful thing about Ubuntu is the kernel identifies the hardware used and gives them generic, useful drivers.  If the drivers are 3rd party or not supported by open sourced drivers then Ubuntu will fetch them for you and let you know.